# Ember: Add conditions in form-element to display field contents

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How to add conditions in Ember template.
What I want to achieve is like this condition.

```
if(modalForAdd == true) // if modalForAdd is true then set the model or the property of each input textfield to blank
{
  {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property=""}}
}
else 
{
  {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property="model.quantity"}}
}
```

Here is my code for template

```
    {{#bs-modal open=openModalForDetails title="Add new Order" body=false footer=false}}
    {{#bs-modal-body}}
       {{#bs-form model=this action=(action "SaveNewOrder" model "this")}}
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Item SKU" property="model.item" id="item"}} 
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property="model.quantity" id="quantity"}} 
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Description" property="model.description" id="description"}} 
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Discount" property="model.discount" id="discount"}} 
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Coupon" property="model.coupon" id="coupon"}} 
          {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Price" property="model.price" id="price"}} 
       {{/bs-form}}
    {{/bs-modal-body}}
    {{bs-modal-footer closeTitle="Cancel" submitTitle="Add"}}
{{/bs-modal}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` helper has an [inline version](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_if) that can be used as subexpression.

You can just do:

```
{{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property=(if modalForAdd "" "model.quantity")}}
```

Comment: It's not working on my end, 


DEBUG: Ember      : 1.13.7
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.13.8
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3

But anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ember.js conditionals ?

```
{{#if modalForAdd}}
  {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property=""}}
{{else}}
  {{bs-form-element controlType="text" label="Quantity" property="model.quantity"}}
{{/if}}
```

More information can be found here https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/conditionals/

Comment: Yeah, it seems working for me. but I'm looking for any other better approach or idea instead. Making my code looks cleaner than the above code, Since I only want to manipulate the property.